# "CorrelationResponse context should not be null" in window workflow 4.0

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity, correlation

I am developing a windows workflow 4 service that has multiple receives. I am handling all the exceptions and there isnt any unhandled exception thrown by the service. I have two reply activities one that sends a faultException and the other that sends the actual reply.

on the first receive activity i receive the response but on the second one if there is an exception, the fault is returned but any subsequent request to the second receive throws a

**The operation could not be performed because the instance is in suspended state.**

If i check the tracking through windows appfabric dashboard the workflow is actually suspended with the following error

**CorrelationResponse context should not be null. This could be because the correlation handle is not setup correctly.**

There is nothing in the CorrelationInitializers on the reply activities and I dont really want the workflow to suspend and to receive additional requests.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Waheed

Answer (score 0):

I finally got to the bottom of it. Following post has the solution.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/df4dacba-4197-4dda-8b91-abddc1da35b6?prof=required

Thanks,
Waheed
http://whussain.wordpress.com